# Visual Studio Community 2015 Installing Android API Level 8

Tags: android, sdk, visual-studio-2015

I installed VS2015 community to try its android development capability.

During the installation I was notified that certain needed components were already present (I have android studio installed).

After starting a project and in its property settings under Application I only have 3 API levels to target.

Under the label "Compile using Android version:" the 3 options are...

API level 19,
API level 21,
API level 22

The SDK's I have installed in Android studio are

8,
19,
21,
22

I need to target android 2.2 froyo minimum which I believe is API level 8.

How can I add ability to use API level 8?

Here is the contents of error window which shows when I try to run a test app...

"Target device (emulator-5554) has an API level of 8, but this application has a minimum API level of 11 set.

The minimum API level can be changed in the project properties on the Android Manifest tab."

I am very new to Android development, and apologise for any incorrect terminology, or if the question seems too basic.

PS, the tag says visual studio preview, it is not.

Comment: Are you installed all Android SDK Build-tools ?

Comment: Yes, they are all installed, everything I could possibly install I did. But there is no option to set minimum API level to 8.

Comment: I install all in sdk manager. eaten 50+GB disk space, still found API8 in project property, least is 10. may be it dropped.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause, not in Android-SDK

The problem in `Xamarin.Android.SDK` ( aka `mono-android`)

Use it's 4.6 Version should can find 2.2 target framework in project property.

But it used a old version Android-SDK and only support vs2012...

You can do a trick to let it useable in vs2015:

> 0) Find the match version `Android-SDK`, my working fine version is 21.1;
>
> 1)Install `Xamarin.VisualStudio` and unselet `Xamarin.Android.SDK`;
>
> 2)Install `mono-android` 4.6;

Now you can build mono android 2.2 in vs 2015.